# Min and max row from pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which I grouped on column 'groupID'.

```
gb = df.groupby('groupID')
```

Each row is a has a x and y coordinate and a residual (distance from the line x=y). Now I want to find the gradient between 2 points(x,y) in a group where the residual is the biggest and the smallest. I know how to use gb['residual'].min() and max() but that does not give me the row.

How can I calculate this?

```
df[gb ['residual'].idxmin()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need find all indices from max and min value of column `residual` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('groupID').residual.idxmax()]
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('groupID').residual.idxmin()]
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Didn't know about `loc`

Comment: @SriK - Problem is your `observation_timestamp` column have no datetimes, need `df.observation_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(observation_timestamp)` first